# Submitting data to database no errors received but no data

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I am using x10hosting.com, I have set up a database and a user for the database, I have also coded the register user page but when I enter all the data and click submit I do not receive any error messages so I am guessing it is connecting to the database just fine but no data is being saved to the tables in the database, here is my code. Any suggestions would be helpful as I have revised my code multiple times now but still nothing has fixed it

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
?>   <!-- The HTML registration form -->
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
       Please fill the following form to sign up:<br /><br />

        Username*: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
        Password*: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
        Password Verify*: <input type="password" name="passwordVeri" /><br />
        First name: <input type="text" name="firstName" /><br />
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lastName" /><br />
        Email*: <input type="type" name="emailAddress" /><br />
        Relationship Status*: <input type="type" select name="relationshipStatus" /><br />
        <option value="Single">Single</option>
        <option value="Taken">Taken</option>            
        </select> 
        Country*: <input type="type" name="country" /><br />
        City*: <input type="type" name="city" /><br />
        Postcode*: <input type="type" name="postCode" /><br />
        Mobile number*: <input type="type" name="mobileNumber" /><br />
        Gender*: <input type="type" select name="gender" /><br />
        <option value="Single">Single</option>
        <option value="Taken">Taken</option>            
        </select>
        Date of Birth*: <input type="type" name="dateOfBirth" /> (Format: DD-MM-YYYY)<br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
<?php


} else {
## connect mysql server
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    # check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();


    # protect data for insertion
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $emailAddress = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emailAddress']);
    $firstName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstName']);           
    $lastName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastName']);                             
    $country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);                          
    $city = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);                            
    $relationshipStatus = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['relationshipStatus']);                           
    $postCode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postCode']);                            
    $mobileNumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mobileNumber']);                             
    $dateOfBirth = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dateOfBirth']);                           
    $gender = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);                             

         //set every user to 0
        $_POST['accountType'] = 0;
        $accountType = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['accountType']);                       

    //check if the two passwords are identical
      if($_POST['password']==$_POST['passwordVeri'])
      {
      }
       else
      {
    //Otherwise,  passwords are not identical
         echo "<p>Passwords do not match!</p>";;
      }

      //We check if the password has 6 or more characters
      if(strlen($_POST['password'])>=6)
      {
      }
       else
      {
    //Otherwise,  passwords are not identical
         echo "<p>Password must be 6 or more characters!</p>";;
      }

    //We check if the email form is valid
              if(preg_match('#^(([a-z0-9!\#$%&\\\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+\.?)*[a-z0-9!\#$%&\\\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)@(([a-z0-9-_]+\.?)*[a-z0-9-_]+)\.[a-z]{2,}$#i',
              $_POST['emailAddress']))
           {
           }
           else
           {
               //Otherwise,  email not valid
         echo "<p>The email you entered is not valid.!</p>";;
      }


    # check if username and email exist else insert
    $exists = 0;
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT username from User WHERE username = '{$username}' LIMIT 1");
    if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
        $exists = 1;
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT emailAddress from Member WHERE emailAddress = '{$emailAddress}' LIMIT 1");
        if ($result->num_rows == 1) $exists = 2; 
    } else {
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT emailAddress from Member WHERE emailAddress = '{$emailAddress}' LIMIT 1");
        if ($result->num_rows == 1) $exists = 3;
    }

    if ($exists == 1) echo "<p>Username already exists!</p>";
    else if ($exists == 2) echo "<p>Username and Email already exists!</p>";
    else if ($exists == 3) echo "<p>Email already exists!</p>";
    else {
        # insert data into mysql database
        $sql = "INSERT  INTO `user` (`Userid`, `username`, `password`, `accountType`) 
                VALUES (NULL, '{$username}', '{$password}', '{$accountType}')";
                "INSERT  INTO `Member` (`firstName`, `lastName`, `gender`, `emailAddress`, `city`, `country`, `postCode`, `relationshipStatus`, `mobileNumber`) 
                VALUES (NULL, '{$firstName}', '{$lastName}', '{$gender}', '{$emailAddress}', '{$city}', '{$country}', '{$postCode}', '{$relationshipStatus}',               '{$mobileNumber}')";

        if ($mysqli->query($sql)) {
            //echo "New Record has id ".$mysqli->insert_id;
            echo "<p>Registred successfully!</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}</p>";
            exit();
        }
    }
    }
}

 ?>
```

Comment: Seems like our comments have been deleted by SO. To close the question as per our conversation, click the checkmark beside my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you're mixing `mysql_` with `mysqli_` functions.

Also, your `INSERT`'s columns and `VALUES` do not match. You have 9x columns for your INSERT and 10x VALUES for your `Member` table (VALUES).

```
$sql = "INSERT  INTO `user` (`Userid`, `username`, `password`, `accountType`) 
VALUES (NULL, '{$username}', '{$password}', '{$accountType}')";
"INSERT  INTO `Member` (`firstName`, `lastName`, `gender`, `emailAddress`, `city`, `country`, `postCode`, `relationshipStatus`, `mobileNumber`) 
VALUES (NULL, '{$firstName}', '{$lastName}', '{$gender}', '{$emailAddress}', '{$city}', '{$country}', '{$postCode}', '{$relationshipStatus}', '{$mobileNumber}')";
```

Either remove the NULL for your Member query or add the appropriate USER_ID field for it, before firstName. That alone will stop your query from executing.

To use `mysqli_real_escape_string`, you will need to change what you presently have, to:

```
# protect data for insertion
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['password']);
$emailAddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['emailAddress']);
$firstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['firstName']);           
$lastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['lastName']);                             
$country = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['country']);                          
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['city']);                            
$relationshipStatus = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['relationshipStatus']);                           
$postCode = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['postCode']);                            
$mobileNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['mobileNumber']);                             
$dateOfBirth = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['dateOfBirth']);                           
$gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['gender']);                             

 //set every user to 0
$_POST['accountType'] = 0;
$accountType = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['accountType']);
```

Also, you could do what you did for your first query by doing the following:

```
$sql2 =  "INSERT  INTO `Member` (`firstName`, `lastName`, `gender`, `emailAddress`, `city`, `country`, `postCode`, `relationshipStatus`, `mobileNumber`) 
        VALUES ('{$firstName}', '{$lastName}', '{$gender}', '{$emailAddress}', '{$city}', '{$country}', '{$postCode}', '{$relationshipStatus}', '{$mobileNumber}')";

if ($mysqli->query($sql2)) {
//echo "New Record has id ".$mysqli->insert_id;
echo "<p>Member table updated successfully!</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>MySQL Member table error no {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}</p>";
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a problem with brackets:

```
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
    exit();
    ...blablah your entire code...
}
```

Instead of:

```
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
    exit();
}
    ...blablah your entire code...
```

So your code will be never executed. This is the correct version:

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
?>   <!-- The HTML registration form -->
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
       Please fill the following form to sign up:<br /><br />

        Username*: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
        Password*: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
        Password Verify*: <input type="password" name="passwordVeri" /><br />
        First name: <input type="text" name="firstName" /><br />
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lastName" /><br />
        Email*: <input type="type" name="emailAddress" /><br />
        Relationship Status*: <input type="type" select name="relationshipStatus" /><br />
        <option value="Single">Single</option>
        <option value="Taken">Taken</option>            
        </select> 
        Country*: <input type="type" name="country" /><br />
        City*: <input type="type" name="city" /><br />
        Postcode*: <input type="type" name="postCode" /><br />
        Mobile number*: <input type="type" name="mobileNumber" /><br />
        Gender*: <input type="type" select name="gender" /><br />
        <option value="Single">Single</option>
        <option value="Taken">Taken</option>            
        </select>
        Date of Birth*: <input type="type" name="dateOfBirth" /> (Format: DD-MM-YYYY)<br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
<?php


} else {
## connect mysql server
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    # check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();
    }

    # protect data for insertion
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $emailAddress = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emailAddress']);
    $firstName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstName']);           
    $lastName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastName']);                             
    $country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);                          
    $city = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);                            
    $relationshipStatus = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['relationshipStatus']);                           
    $postCode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postCode']);                            
    $mobileNumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mobileNumber']);                             
    $dateOfBirth = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dateOfBirth']);                           
    $gender = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);                             

         //set every user to 0
    $_POST['accountType'] = 0;
    $accountType = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['accountType']);                       

    //check if the two passwords are identical
    if($_POST['password']==$_POST['passwordVeri'])
    {
    }
     else
    {
    //Otherwise,  passwords are not identical
         echo "<p>Passwords do not match!</p>";;
    }

    //We check if the password has 6 or more characters
    if(strlen($_POST['password'])>=6)
    {
    }
     else
    {
    //Otherwise,  passwords are not identical
         echo "<p>Password must be 6 or more characters!</p>";;
    }

    //We check if the email form is valid
    if(preg_match('#^(([a-z0-9!\#$%&\\\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+\.?)*[a-z0-9!\#$%&\\\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)@(([a-z0-9-_]+\.?)*[a-z0-9-_]+)\.[a-z]{2,}$#i',
              $_POST['emailAddress']))
           {
           }
           else
           {
               //Otherwise,  email not valid
         echo "<p>The email you entered is not valid.!</p>";;
      }


    # check if username and email exist else insert
    $exists = 0;
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT username from User WHERE username = '{$username}' LIMIT 1");
    if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
        $exists = 1;
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT emailAddress from Member WHERE emailAddress = '{$emailAddress}' LIMIT 1");
        if ($result->num_rows == 1) $exists = 2; 
    } else {
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT emailAddress from Member WHERE emailAddress = '{$emailAddress}' LIMIT 1");
        if ($result->num_rows == 1) $exists = 3;
    }

    if ($exists == 1) echo "<p>Username already exists!</p>";
    else if ($exists == 2) echo "<p>Username and Email already exists!</p>";
    else if ($exists == 3) echo "<p>Email already exists!</p>";
    else {
        # insert data into mysql database
        $sql = "INSERT  INTO `user` (`Userid`, `username`, `password`, `accountType`) 
                VALUES (NULL, '{$username}', '{$password}', '{$accountType}')";
                "INSERT  INTO `Member` (`firstName`, `lastName`, `gender`, `emailAddress`, `city`, `country`, `postCode`, `relationshipStatus`, `mobileNumber`) 
                VALUES (NULL, '{$firstName}', '{$lastName}', '{$gender}', '{$emailAddress}', '{$city}', '{$country}', '{$postCode}', '{$relationshipStatus}',               '{$mobileNumber}')";

        if ($mysqli->query($sql)) {
            //echo "New Record has id ".$mysqli->insert_id;
            echo "<p>Registred successfully!</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}</p>";
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```